# Docker - mongoDB: failed to connect to server [mongo:27017] on first connect

Tags: mongodb, docker, dockerfile

When I run my docker container I get this error
This is my server.js

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://mongo/allin")
```

My dockerfile

```
FROM mongo:latest AS mongo 
WORKDIR /data
VOLUME ["/data/db"]
EXPOSE 27017


FROM node:latest
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm i
COPY . /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 4000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what. I don't want use docker-compose.

Thanks

Comment: Have you double-checked that your mongo container is up and running and listening for connections?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that nodejs container need link to mongodb container

Comment: Could you please paste your **docker run** arguments of both containers and the error mongoose raised?